# How to verify a function doesn't call itself?

Tags: c++, linux, c++11, gcc, crtp

Here is my code, here you see object of type `Base` with interface function `Do()`, I always use objects of type `Base` (templated with more types) and always call the `Do()` interface. So with `ImplBaseDummy1`, and `ImplBaseDummy2` I get either the specific implementation of `f()` for `ImplBaseDummy2` or the default implementation from `Base` in case of `ImplBaseDummy1`. All this worked great so far, I have a lot of code that works as expected and I prefer not to change the API but I might do so if you can convince me I should. Recently I had to add more types like `ImplBase` I try never to duplicate code so I created a similar structure hoping it will continue to work. The problem is how to enforce calling specific implementations of `f` when defined and use the default implementation (from `Base`) when specific implementation is missing, all this should happen when calling the interface function `Do()` for objects of type `Base` (templated somehow).

```
#include <iostream>

template <class Impl>
class Base
{
public:
 void Do() { f_impl(); }
 void f() {std::cout << "Base::f" << std::endl; }
protected:
 void f_impl() { static_cast<Impl*>(this)->f(); }
};

class ImplBaseDummy1 : public Base<ImplBaseDummy1>
{
};

class ImplBaseDummy2 : public Base<ImplBaseDummy2>
{
public:
 void f() {std::cout << "ImplBaseDummy2::f" << std::endl; }
};

template <class Actual>
class ImplBase : public Base<ImplBase<Actual>>
{
public:
 typedef Base<ImplBase<Actual>> Parent;
 void f() { static_cast<Actual*>(this)->f(); }
};

class Derived1 : public ImplBase<Derived1>
{
public:
 typedef ImplBase<Derived1> Parent;
 void f() {std::cout << "Derived1::f" << std::endl; }
};

class Derived2 : public ImplBase<Derived2>
{
public:
 typedef ImplBase<Derived2> Parent;
 using Parent::Parent::f;
};

int main()
{
  Base<ImplBaseDummy1> d01;
  d01.Do();
  Base<ImplBaseDummy2> d02;
  d02.Do();
  Base<ImplBase<Derived1>> d1;
  d1.Do();
  Base<ImplBase<Derived2>> d2;
  d2.Do();
  return 0;
}
```

This code compiles and runs as expected. My question regards to safety mechanism I would like to implement in case I forget to write `using Parent::Parent::f;` in `Derived2` (which was the initial intention, in case a specific implementation is missing call the default implementation from `Base`). What happens in this case is that `ImplBase<Derived2>::f()` calls itself indefinitely until it crashes (or never exits when compiling `-O3` optimization level). I wanted to implement it similar to this

```
void f() { static_assert(&f != &Actual::f, "function calls itself"); static_cast<Actual*>(this)->f(); }
void f() { static_assert(!std::is_same<decltype(f), decltype(Actual::f)>::value, "function calls itself"); static_cast<Actual*>(this)->f(); }
```

But both implementation don't compile, any other ideas how to implement this check? To emphasize, a run time solution is not what I'm looking for, I'm better off any check and just break my head when I come across an issue instead executing an additional test for any call to the `Do` interface.

Comment: You could use [__PRETTY_FUNCTION__](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Names.html) to see which function is called and when

Comment: You won't be able to detect indirect recursion in all cases (e.g. your function calling `foo` which calls `bar` which calls your function).

Comment: @Bl4ckb0ne, it would be great if I could compare at compile time  PRETTY_FUNCTION from ImplBase::f and the PRETTY_FUNCTION of Actual::f but I don't think it can be done.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch, I would like to address very specific case, not the general one

Comment: How many months are you willing to spend to code your verifier?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch +1 for you comment, actually very little bu tI prefer not more than few hours. I understand that this is something that for some reason this is hard to do but I don't understand why if the `static_cast` can be resolved at compile time why can't `static_assert` work as well?

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible to prove re-entry at compile time in general.

But it can be checked at runtime:

```
static bool inside = false;
assert(!inside);
inside = true;

// rest of function

inside = false;
return whatever; // if non void
```

The destructors of local variables can still technically end up calling the function. That can be partially solved with a (reusable) RAII-style object:

```
class nonreentrant
{
    bool& inside;
    public:
    nonreentrant(bool& inside): inside(inside)
    {
        assert(!this->inside);
        this->inside = true;
    }
    ~nonreentrant()
    {
        this->inside = false;
    }
};

// usage
static bool inside = false;
nonreentrant guard(inside);

// rest of function
```

Unfortunately, this does not work with the parameters, whose destructors will be run after.

Technically it's still possible that some move constructor involved with returning the value might end up calling the function. Void functions and those returning trivially movable objects should be foolproof.

Comment: A run time solution will not work here, I need to verify my code at compile time or take my chances and use no validation at all. I understand that in general it is not possible to prove re-entry at compile time, but I'm not talking about the general case, this is a very specific implementation that I wish to validate. Fact is that `static_cast<Actual*>(this)->f()` resolves to the right thing (at compile time) so I don't understand how come I can't validate anything about this resolution at compile time

Answer (score 1):

Your code executes undefined behavior, so there is no way to "check if it is working correctly".  The standard places zero requirements on the behavior of your program; all behavior is "correct".

`ImplBase<Derived2>` is not a `Derived2`, so the `static_cast<Derived2*>(this)->f()` causes undefined behavior to result.  An infinite loop here is as correct as what you want to happen.

I have solved similar problems without doing undefined behavior.

```
template <class Impl>
class Base {
public:
  void f_impl() {std::cout << "Base::f" << std::endl; }
};
template <class Actual>
class ImplBase : public Base<ImplBase<Actual>> {
public:
  void f() { static_cast<Actual*>(this)->f_impl(); }
};

class Derived1 : public ImplBase<Derived1> {
public:
  void f_impl() {std::cout << "Derived1::f" << std::endl; }
};

class Derived2 : public ImplBase<Derived2> {
public:
};
```

Now, `Derived1 d1; d1.f();` and `Derived2 d2; d2.f();` does what I believe you want; `d1` has overriden `f`, while `d2` uses the `Base` behavior.

We split interface from implementation, permitting the implementation dispatch to exist independent of the interface dispatch.

Comment: I prefer not change the interface but I might do so if what I am doing is wrong. If you don't mind, I updated the code I'm using a bit further to reflect what it does, please let me know if you have another suggestion  given that `Base` has `Do()` function as the interface I'm using which calls `f()` so I'm forced to use this name

Comment: @e27 your code still has undefined behaviour.  You cannot cast a pointer to a type it is not then interaft with it, period.

Answer (score 1):

Dont't declare using Parent::Parent::f. delcare an f() that calls parent::Parent::f() explicitly.  That would solve your problem.

If you want extra protection against forgetting about declaration, you should declare your final classes with protected inheritance, as in:

```
class Derived1 : protected ImplBase<Derived1>
{
public:
 typedef ImplBase<Derived1> Parent;
 void f() {std::cout << "Derived1::f" << std::endl; }
};

class Derived2 : protected ImplBase<Derived2>
{
public:
 typedef ImplBase<Derived2> Parent;
 // void f() { Parent::Parent::f(); }  // uncomment to avoid compile error.
};
```

The error message generated is quite clear and mentions the faulty class by name.

This code is quite contrived.  I have a hard time figuring out in what purpose such inheritance will be useful, since simply directly declaring objects of type Derived1 or Derived2 objects directly would work quite fine without any need for ImplBase<>::f() in your original code.

Is that related to meta-programming? We are very interested.

Here is the complete solution, with 4 lines of code changed.

```
#include <iostream>

template <class Impl>
class Base
{
public:
    void Do() { f_impl(); }
    void f() { std::cout << "Base::f" << std::endl; }
protected:
    void f_impl() { static_cast<Impl*>(this)->f(); }
};

class ImplBaseDummy1 : public Base<ImplBaseDummy1>
{
};

class ImplBaseDummy2 : public Base<ImplBaseDummy2>
{
public:
    static void f() { std::cout << "ImplBaseDummy2::f" << std::endl; }
};

template <class Actual>
class ImplBase : public Base<ImplBase<Actual>>
{
public:
    typedef Base<ImplBase<Actual>> Parent;
    void f() { static_cast<Actual*>(this)->f(); }
};

class Derived1 : protected ImplBase<Derived1>
{
public:
    typedef ImplBase<Derived1> Parent;
    void f() { std::cout << "Derived1::f" << std::endl; }
};

class Derived2 : protected ImplBase<Derived2>
{
public:
    typedef ImplBase<Derived2> Parent;
    //using Parent::Parent::f;
    //void f() { Parent::Parent::f(); } // uncomment to remove compile error
};

int main()
{
    Base<ImplBaseDummy1> d01;
    d01.Do();
    Base<ImplBaseDummy2> d02;
    d02.Do();
    Base<ImplBase<Derived1>> d1;
    d1.Do();
    Base<ImplBase<Derived2>> d2;
    d2.Do();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The problem is that I will forget to implement `f`in `Derived2` I need something to remind me this (a compilation error would be great)

Comment: I see... Making ImplBase<>::f() protected will generate the error you want, if you, or the next developer, forgets to define f().

Comment: @e271p314  What compiler is this for?

Comment: I'm using gcc 5.3.1, please note I must keep ` ImplBase<>::f()` public because it is called from `Base` with the `Do` interface

Comment: The above suggestion works for the Dummy classes as well, either way.  since the Dummy family uses a different hierarchy.

Comment: Thank you very much for looking into this issue. I compiled and run your code with `g++ -O3 -std=c++11 test.cpp -o test; ./test`, the code compiles and gets stuck (since `Derived2 ` does not implement `f()`) I want to know at compile time I did something wrong (forgot to implement `f()` in `Derived2 `) also please note `static` is not required in `ImplBaseDummy2::f()` I also updated the code in the question

Comment: Sorry, I'm at work.  I only have access to VS2017 at the moment, and have more concrete problems  to solve atm.